# Conditionals by row with Formattable package in R

Tags: r, conditional-formatting, formattable

I want to know how to assign a conditional format to a table so that each row has a different condition that needs to be fulfilled. So that in statistic row, if the value <0.96 it turns red, and in the case of p-value row if the value is > 0.05 it turns red.

I'm formatting from the following dataframe

```
df_try
    Normal        Jan        Feb
1  stistic 0.93069466 0.90404849
2 p-values 0.05123532 0.01056474
```

My condition formatting is in the code imporvement_formatter but naturally, it turns all values red because all are <0.96. I need a second condition for the next row that works for the >0.05 condition

```
i2 <- df_try %>%
+   select(c(`Normal`,`Jan`, `Feb`))
> formattable(i2)
improvement_formatter <- 
+   formatter("span", 
+             style = x ~ style(
+               font.weight = "bold", 
+               color = ifelse(x < 0.96, customRed, "black")))
> 
> formattable(i2, align =c("l","c","c"), list(
+   `Indicator Name` = 
+     formatter("span", style = ~ style(color = "grey",font.weight = "bold")), 
+   `Jan` = improvement_formatter
+ ))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the `area` function. It helps to use formatters on rows and not just on columns. So you can define your formatters like you did and then use them specificly on certain rows and columns. Here is an example:

```
library(formattable)

df_try <- structure(list(Normal = structure(2:1, .Label = c("p-values", 
                                                            "stistic"), class = "factor"), Jan = c(0.93069466, 0.05123532
                                                            ), Feb = c(0.90404849, 0.01056474)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
                                                                                                                                     "2"))

first_col_formatter <- formatter("span", 
                                 style = ~ style(color = "grey",
                                                 font.weight = "bold"))

improvement_formatter <- formatter("span", 
                style = x ~ style(
                font.weight = "bold", 
                color = ifelse(x < 0.96, "red", "black")))

improvement2_formatter <- formatter("span", 
                                   style = x ~ style(
                                     font.weight = "bold", 
                                     color = ifelse(x > 0.05, "red", "black")))

formattable(df_try,
            align =c("l","c","c"),
            list(Normal = first_col_formatter,
              area(row = 1, col = -1) ~ improvement_formatter,
                 area(row = 2, col = -1) ~ improvement2_formatter))
```

[image]